# python print directories listing from input list of files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a high level directory structure (without duplication) from given input list of files.

Ex: Input files list is,

```
li=['a/b/c.txt','a/b/d/cc.txt','a/e/f.txt', 'g/h/i.txt','j/k.txt','l/m.txt']
```

and output to be like

```
a
+----b
     +----d
+----e
g
+----h
j
l
```

I did go through similar posts on stack overflow (before posting this question), but most of the posts had inputs with no duplicates or tree like structure or directory listing from local (and none of those cases match with the problem I'm looking at)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use Trie in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70539497/8677071 , then print the final `dict` generated in your required format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
def generate_nested_dirs(dir_list):
    nested_dirs={}
    for d in dir_list:
        temp=nested_dirs
        for sub_dir in d.split("/"):
            if temp.get(sub_dir) is None:
                temp[sub_dir]={}
            temp=temp[sub_dir]
    return nested_dirs


def print_dirs(input_dict,indent):
    for dir in list(input_dict):
        if indent == 0:
            print(dir)
        else:
            print('\t'*indent,'+--->',dir)
        if input_dict[d]:
            print(input_dict[dir], indent+1)
```

And finally calling the above two functions,

```
li=['a/b/c.txt','a/b/d/cc.txt','a/e/f.txt', 'g/h/i.txt','j/k.txt','l/m.txt']
all_dirs=[]
for f in li:
            all_dirs.append("/".join(f.split("/")[1:-1]))
all_dirs=sorted(set(all_dirs))
to_print=generate_nested_dirs(all_dirs)
print_dirs(to_print)
```

And output will be

```
a
    +----b
        +----d
    +----e
g
    +----h
j
l
```

Note: Part of the solution was through ['trie' approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538768/looking-for-an-efficient-method-or-algorithm-to-check-whether-a-file-belongs-to/70539497#70539497)